# Idiomatic way to find a matching line in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an `Iterable[String]` representing the lines in a file and I'd like to find the first line in that sequence that matches a regular expression and return a numerical value extracted by the regex. The file is big enough that it wouldn't make sense to load the whole thing into memory and then call `toString()` or something, so I'll need to go through it a line at a time.

Here's what I have (it works):

```
val RateRegex : Regex = ".....".r

def getRate(source : Source) : Option[Double] = {
  import java.lang.Double._

  for(line <- source.getLines() ) {
    line match {
      case RateRegex(rawRate) => return Some(parseDouble(rawRate))
      case None => ()
    }
  }

  return None
}
```

This seems ugly to me. It feels very imperative and `case None => ()` might as well be replaced with a comment that says "you're doing it wrong."

I think I want something like `def findFirstWhereNonNone(p : Function[A,Option[B]]) => Option[B]` where the collection's elements are of type `A`.

Are there built-in methods that would let me do this in a more functional way? Should I just write that method?

P.S. While I'm at it, is there an alternative to using `java.lang.Double.parseDouble`? Scala's `Double` class doesn't expose it.

P.P.S I've seen a lot of posts on SO suggesting that the `Source` API shouldn't be used in production, but they're all from 2008 and 2009. Is that still the case? If so, what should I use for IO?

## Update

I now have:

```
import util.matching.Regex.Groups

for{line <- source.getLines()
    Groups(rawRate) <- RateRegex.findFirstMatchIn(line)} {
  return Some(parseDouble(rawRate))
}

return None
```

which feels a lot better to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: This third alternative ia quite neat:

```
source
.getLines()
.collectFirst{ case RateRegex(x) => x.toDouble}
```

Not sure if it's more functional, but you can use the behaviour of foreach/for-comprehensions on Options

```
def getRate(source : Source) : Option[Double] = {

     for {line    <- source.getLines() 
          rawRate <- RateRegex.findFirstIn(line)}
       return  Some(rawRate toDouble)

  return None
}
```

This works too (quite similar to EasyAngel's answer):

```
source
.getLines()
.map{RateRegex.findFirstMatchIn(_)}
.filter{_.isDefined}
.map{_.get.group(0).toDouble}
.head
.toList
.headOption
```

The last three are a little ugly. The take(1) is to ensure we only evaluate up to the first match. The toList is to force the evaluation, and the headOption to extract the first value as Some() or None if there is none. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to replace `rawRate <- RateRegex.findFirstIn(line)` with `RateRegex(rawMatch) <- line`? I tried it but now I always return `None`. Much easier that way, since the target number is in a match group.

Comment: You can replace `rawRate <- findFirstIn` with `match <- findFirstMatchIn` and then use `match.group(N).toDouble`

Comment: Unfortunately `headOption` is not defined neither in `Iterator` nor in `TraversableOnce` (it's defined in `TraversableLike` though). Also in your second `map`, argument is of type `Option[Regex.Match]`, so it will not compile.

Comment: @EasyAngel, yes, removed the alternative. There's got to be something similar that should work, though. I'll think about it a bit harder.

Comment: I updated my question with a solution based on the `Groups` extractor. Using the `RateRegex(rawRate)` pattern on the LHS of the for pattern doesn't seem to work, even though it should be returning an `Option[List[String]]`. But with the RateRegex extractor, the body of the for loop is never executed.

Comment: See my third alternative just posted. Quite neat, even if I say so myself

Comment: +1 The third alternative is really nice. Seems that `collectFirst` comes from Scala 2.9. But `headOption` is not needed, because `collectFirst` already returns `Option[Double]`

Comment: @WasyAngel, yes I'm using 2.9 and I didn't check it was in 2.8. I think it's just collect{...}.take(1).toList.headOption though in this case? And thanks for the point about headOption - edited my answer

Comment: @Paul Neat indeed! collectFirst is very good to know about, though I'm still on 2.8. However, if it really expands to "collect(...).take(1).toList.headOption" that will loop through every line, won't it? "view.collect(...).take(1).toList.headOption" would avoid that, I think.

Comment: I don't think so, because the iterator (getlines) is already lazy (although I didn't test this)

Comment: It does; I verified to make sure. `map` loops through all of the lines before returning

Comment: @Paul Please allow me to retract that. I made a mistake; you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the possible solutions:

```
def getRates(source : Source) = source.getLines.map {
    case RateRegex(rate) => Some(rate toDouble)
    case _ => None
} filter (_ isDefined) toList
```

Please note, that this function now returns now `List[Option[Double]]` of all found rates. It's also important, that Iterator remains lazy until I call `toList`

---

### Update

As was asked in comments, here is solution, that returns only first occurrence:

```
def getRate(source : Source): Option[Double] = source.getLines.map {
  case RateRegex(rate) => Some(rate toDouble)
  case _ => None
} find (_ isDefined) getOrElse None
```

Comment: And so potentially does a lot more work reading/matching the rest of the lines. Can you replace `toList` with `headOption` and keep the OP's return value (and still be lazy)?

Comment: Right. `map` occurred to me, but I don't want to have to read the entire file if I find the target rate early on.

Comment: @Easy Angel that will still loop through every line

Comment: @Bill: Yes, it will iterate through each line in file **until** rate would be found (so it will **not** iterate the whole file if rate is somewhere in the middle). You can't avoid this unless you are using `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: @Easy Angel It does loop through the whole file. Try it. Put a println in the function you pass to `map`. Map goes through its entire input.

Comment: @Bill: I tested it exactly as you described before posting previous comment and made sure that it's don't. I double-checked it now with real file and received the same results - iterator is **not** going through whole file if rate is found. Sorry, but seems that you are making something wrong.